# How to filter the geoserver WMS getCapabilities request?

Tags: geoserver

In the [GeoServer WMS reference](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html), It is written that the namespace can limit the response to layers. But I didn't find any resources related to the `namespace`. Can anyone help me to understand what `namespace` mean? Does it mean `workspace`?

I have tried to put the value of the namespace as my `workspace` name and also `layer_name`. Both tries did not work and I am getting the full WMS capabilities. Is there any way to filter our capabilities response to the specific layer?

Comment: What WMS reference do you mean?

Comment: I mean the GeoServer WMS reference document. Sorry I updated the question with the correct document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the name of your workspace, so for example:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=wms&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities&namespace=topp
```

returns only the layers in the `topp` namespace.

If you are having problems with the size of the capabilities document you may also want to [limit the number of SRS](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/webadmin.html#limited-srs-list) that are reported.

Comment: Thank you @Ian for the clarification. I found that the `namespace` filter will not work for the `WMS` version `1.0.0`, `1.1.1` and `1.1.0`. These versions will download all the layer information from the entire GeoServer. PS: I am using the GeoServer version 2.17.2`

Comment: that sounds like a bug - please report it at https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/GEOS/issues/

Comment: Or just use the workspace specific path instead, should work with any version and protocol: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/topp/ows?service=wms&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities